# Joomla - Create my own form

Tags: php, html, forms, joomla

I developed a site with joomla CMS and I want to create a membership form with paypal. Users will register and pay some money in order to see some menus in my site. After a lot of searching I found a plugin that helps me to create a form and insert user data into database. But I dont know the way to manipulate these data from database.. Maybe I should create the form with HTML and write php..  Any idea?

Comment: don't you have database credentials?

Comment: Not yet but I'll do it.

Comment: I want to create a membership form with paypal.. Is there any way to do it without source code ?

Comment: plugins are your friends

Comment: I know, I found this plugin http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/billing-a-invoices/payment-form   but I don't know the way to manipulate data from database after inserted. For example, user sign up in the membership form and his data inserted to database. After that is there any way to get data and check if this user is active (username password) without code?

Comment: I found this plugin http://joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/membership-pro-joomla-membership-subscription.html  and I think that it is ok! Thank you very much

Comment: no worries was happy coding